# Event .on and .off

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am having a few issues with some events I am making.

On my `document.ready` I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

//deal with clicks

jQuery(".touchslider-prev").click( function() { 
    
    jQuery(window).trigger('swipeForward');
});

jQuery(".touchslider-next").click( function() { 
    
    jQuery(window).trigger('swipeBackward');
});

//deal with swipe 

var maxTime = 1000,
    // allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
    maxDistance = 50,
    // swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the swipe
    target = jQuery('.pageSize'),
    startX = 0,
    startTime = 0,
    touch = "ontouchend" in document,
    startEvent = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
    moveEvent = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    endEvent = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

target.bind(startEvent, function(e) {
    // prevent image drag (Firefox)
    // e.preventDefault();
    startTime = e.timeStamp;
    startX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
}).bind(endEvent, function(e) {
    startTime = 0;
    startX = 0;
}).bind(moveEvent, function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    var currentX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
        currentDistance = (startX === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(currentX - startX),
        // allow if movement < 1 sec
        currentTime = e.timeStamp;
    if (startTime !== 0 && currentTime - startTime < maxTime && currentDistance > maxDistance) {
        if (currentX < startX) {
            // swipe left code here

           console.log("page forward trigger");
           jQuery(window).trigger('swipeForward');

        }
        if (currentX > startX) {
            // swipe right code here
             console.log("page back trigger");
           //slide("back", pageSize);
            jQuery(window).trigger('swipeBackward');
        }
        startTime = 0;
        startX = 0;
    }
});


//handle triggers from click and slide

jQuery(window).on('swipeForward', clickHandlerNext );
jQuery(window).on('swipeBackward', clickHandlerPrev );

});
```

---

If I then click forward or swipe forward this should trigger `swipeForward` which brings this bit of code into play   `jQuery(window).on('swipeForward', clickHandlerNext );`

so the function `clickHandlerNext` should be run

```
function clickHandlerPrev(event) {

if(event.handled !== true) {

        // Kill event handler, preventing any more clicks
        jQuery(window).off("click", clickHandlerPrev);
        jQuery(window).off("click", clickHandlerNext);
        console.log("switch off handlers");

        // Do your stuff here
        slide("back");

        // Mark event as handled
        event.handled = true;
    } 

    return false;
}

function clickHandlerNext(event) {

    // If event isn't already marked as handled, handle it

    if(event.handled !== true) {

        // Kill event handler, preventing any more clicks
        jQuery(window).off("click", clickHandlerPrev);
        jQuery(window).off("click", clickHandlerNext);
        console.log("switch off handlers");

        // Do your stuff here
        slide("forward");

        // Mark event as handled
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this should switch off the handler and then run the slide function.

```
function slide(data) {


        jQuery('#pageHolder').animate({
            left: 950

          }, 400, function() {
            console.log("animation started");
            console.log("switch on handles");
jQuery(window).on("click", clickHandlerPrev);
            jQuery(window).on("click", clickHandlerNext);
     
            console.log("animation complete");

        });


}
```

This then turns back on the handler. If I however remove the line `jQuery(window).on("click", clickHandlerPrev);` the next time I press the button it still runs the handler - but it shouldn't as it should be set `.off`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you prune down the code you posted to the relevant parts?

Comment: Or better yet, post it in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see it in action?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P7DqL/ but this looks as though it works. i am having a problem on the ipad. and really just want to understand what i am doing wrong with my event

Comment: I suggest you use the `jQuery.one` ( http://api.jquery.com/one/ ) instead of using `on` and `off`

Comment: well i do actually want it to come back on afterwards. the idea is that it gets switched off and then back on after the slide. but it seems that the event handler is always true and i am not sure why

Comment: I have resolved the on and off as i had some bad names

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. sometimes this still fails on the ipad though. can anyone see why?

Comment: Dan, your .offs don't correspond to any .ons, so will have precisely zero effect - exactly as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Is [jQuery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) an option? It applies the handler just once.

Comment: well i do actually want it to come back on afterwards. the idea is that it gets switched off and then back on after the slide. but it seems that the event handler is always true and i am not sure why

Comment: sorry. i dont understand why .one is an option

Comment: i had to see your example to see what you were going for. Yeah, in your case I don't believe .one would of been what you needed. But I am glad you resolved your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the fiddle. sometimes this still fails on the ipad though. can you see why?